# Android onActivityResult - value of RESULT_OK

Tags: android, android-activity

In the following code which went past the assignment of `b=` in the innermost block:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // update the contact list
            Bundle b = data.getExtras();
```

I am getting `b` as `null`. So I tried debugging and `resultCode` is shown as `-1` by the debugger.
The question is, is `RESULT_OK` value supposed to be negative?

Answer (score 8):

Yep. `RESULT_OK` has the value -1.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK